# Construct Object from Json/Map (with Annotations)

Tags: java

I have this class that I persist by creating a JSON object based on its annotation:

```
@Entity(name = "user")
public class User { 
    @Id 
    private String id;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column
    private Integer age;
    public User() {}
public User(String id, String name, String age) {}
// ... code omitted
}

boolean ok = createEntity(new User("uid1", "eli", 25));
```

The method above will convert the User object into a Map respresenting a JSON object like:

```
map.put("ID", "uid1");
map.put("name", "eli");
map.put("age", 25);
```

This works fine. However I need to create a User object based on a response map containling values in similar form like the above, first I get the response from the server in form of JSON string:

```
{
    "id" : "uid2",
    "name" : "ben",
    "age" : 20
}
```

I mean, if I parse this JSON string into a map:

```
map.put("id", "uid2");
map.put("name", "ben");
map.put("age", 20);
```

How can I construct a User object filling the values from the map to the correct `@Column` field?

Update:

I know about Jackson library, but the idea here is that I need to work with annotations as I am building a library that needs classes to be annotated. I am just after the way to create object from json/map and assign the right values to the right field

Comment: Always objects would be constructed with annotations. You can process annotation over object later. what u couldn't achieve with JackSon ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) library. It converts your objects to json without the need to annotate them.

Comment: I know about Jackson library, but the idea here is that I need to work with annotations as I am building a library that needs classes to be annotated. I am just after the way to create object from json/map and assign the right values to the right field